# Filter on joined dataframe is not working in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the 3 following columns

- student_id
- name
- timestamp

There are multiple rows for a student id with different names along with the timestamp the record actually updated. I wanted to get 2 different dataframes.

- unique_data (rows of all student ids with latest timestamp for that student id)
- duplicate_data (all the rows from input dataframe except the above mentioned unique_data rows)

I have the following code which generates 2 dataframes

```
input_frame.show()
+----------+----------+---------+
|student_id|name      |timestamp|
+----------+----------+---------+
|        s1|testuser  |       t1|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|
|        s2|test123   |       t1|
|        s2|sample123 |       t2|
+----------+----------+---------+

# Assuming t2 > t1

unique_data = input_frame.sort(sf.desc(timestamp))drop_duplicates("student_id")
unique_data.show()
+----------+----------+---------+
|student_id|name      |timestamp|
+----------+----------+---------+
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|
|        s2|sample123 |       t2|
+----------+----------+---------+

input_frame = input_frame.alias('input_frame')
unique_frame = unique_frame.alias('unique_frame')

joined_data = input_frame.join(unique_data, input_frame["student_id"] == unique_data["student_id"], how="left")
joined_data.show()
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|student_id|name      |timestamp|student_id|name      |timestamp|
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|        s1|testuser  |       t1|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|
|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|        s1|sampleuser|       t2|
|        s2|test123   |       t1|        s2|sample123 |       t2|
|        s2|sample123 |       t2|        s2|sample123 |       t2|
+----------+----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+



duplicate_data = joined_data.filter(input_frame["timestamp"] != unique_data["timestamp"]).select("input_frame.*")
duplicate_data.show()
+----------+----+---------+
|student_id|name|timestamp|
+----------+----+---------+
+----------+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use alias in the filter condition as the frames have similar columns

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

input_frame = input_frame.alias('input_frame')
unique_frame = unique_frame.alias('unique_frame')

duplicate_data = joined_data.filter(sf.col("input_frame.timestamp") != sf.col("unique_data.timestamp")).select("input_frame.*")
duplicate_data.show()
+----------+----------+---------+
|student_id|name      |timestamp|
+----------+----------+---------+
|        s1|testuser  |       t1|
|        s2|test123   |       t1|
+----------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

for the `unique_data["timestamp"]`, if you want to take the whole column, spark does not know which row you are talking about. you are allowed to do something like:

`duplicate_data = joined_data.filter((joined_data.timestamp != unique_data.collect()[0]['timestamp']))`
which says joined_data.timestamp is not equal to the first row of unique_data, [row 0][timestamp]. or you can iterate through every row of unique_data and check whether they are equal or not.